# streaming binary files through a communication port

Tags: java, communication, outputstream, serial-communication

I am pushing binary files through a com port to a module connected to my computer.
right now I am pushing the files one by one every minute and it seems that I should do it using a stream pushing files constantly.
here are my methods for the pushing of the files:

```
public void push2rec (File F, boolean chk){
    try {        
        byte[] read = BinRead(F.getAbsolutePath());
        SP.writeBytes(read);
        if (chk) {F.delete();}              
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {msgArea.append(ex.toString() + "\n");} 
} 

public static byte[] BinRead(String name){
    File file = new File(name);     
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream.read(bytes);
        inputStream.close(); 
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {System.out.println(ex);} 
    catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}

    return bytes;
}
```

SP is a serial port instance.

my question is what would be the best way to do it. Also would it be possible to feed the same file over and over again using a stream until the next file should be pushed? 
a certain file should be pushed every minute, this is very important. That means I can not push many different files in the same minute. it should be a stream of a the same file.

Comment: You could reuse `read` until the File changes, which you must somehow monitor. Sidenote: Isn't it superfluent to have a `File`, get its absolute path as string, pass this to a method where a new Fileobject is created from that? Just pass the File object ...

Comment: That is because the files created before and placed in some directory. during the pushing the files are taken from the directory and pushed to the port.